# Navbar Collapse

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I've tried to make a navbar which looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
     <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">CIDashboard</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#" class="nav-link">LOG OUT</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#" class="nav-link">USER</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

My problem is that I have a space in the right side of the navbar.

[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you post your CSS? Without that, it's not possible to diagnose.

Comment: I put a picture with the navbar

Comment: I don't have CSS

Comment: Only this bootstrap

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in jsfiddle? I copied your code and it works fine, without mentioned space. http://jsfiddle.net/MattCMC/aq9Laaew/191359/

Comment: Post *all* of the relevant code.

Comment: @Matt I don't see my problem in  in jsfiddle.

Comment: i tested your code and it's working fine. If your navbar has a parent element with container class, then there will be surrounding spaces. If so, remove the parent element or add container-fluid class to the parent.

Comment: Sorry, it's work now... didn't work because I had a stupid code below..